# How to find if the device's rotation is stopped in android

Tags: android, rotation, sensors

Is there any way to find if the device is stopped from rotating when dealing with sensors? What I want to do is I want to display some data, if the device is stopped rotating i.e., onSensorChanged() is not hit when the device stopped rotating

I have no idea of the way to implement this.

can anyone please suggest an idea of implementing this!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Rotating with respect to which axis? What is the position of the device in general?

Comment: @Hoan, Rotation is with respect to x-axis.

Comment: Is the device in Portrait orientation?

Comment: yes. device is in Portrait orientation!

Comment: Did you call getOrientation?

Comment: What sensors do you register for?

Comment: I registered for accelerometer sensors

Comment: What do you try to do with the sensor? It is a lot more accurate if you also register for magnetic field sensor and then use the values from getOrientation to determine if the phone stop rotating.